# Is there any NP example that we can get an answer in polynomial time？

Tags: algorithm, np, np-hard

I just read NP and P on wikipedia, I have two questions:

1. Can we solve an NP example in polynomial time ?
2. Is there any NP example that we can get an answer in polynomial time？

Comment: What do you mean by "solved"?

Comment: I mean is there any NP example that we can get an answer in polynomial time.

Comment: What do you understand the "NP problem" to be? Your question is hard to decipher with standard terminology.

Comment: @An NP problem to which we can get an answer in polynomial time is not an NP problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But P is a subset of NP. It's only whether P is a *proper* subset of NP or not that keeps us up at night. So any problem in P is an NP problem that we can get an answer to in polynomial time.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight "An X that has property P(X) isn't an X." What?

Comment: @TracyMcGrady I'm not confused with the definition of NP or P, you are; reading wikipedia and understanding what it says are two different things. "So we should say,the NP problem that isn't a P problem we can not get an answer in polynomial time so far." Not just so far, unless P = NP. If something is not in P, then using classical computers, you cannot get a correct algorithm that runs in polynomial time at all, because it doesn't exist by definition.

Comment: @G.Bach That comment is not on you,anyway I was wrong.I understood your words just a moment ago,I think I was in a stupid circle yesterday,I realize that my question is a mistake.....Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This answer focuses on the practical aspects of dealing with the fact that there are problems for which no polynomial-time algorithm is known. To give an answer that is precise from a theoretical point of view, the terminology used in the question is not clear enough.*

There are two meanings of NP in computer science that are easily mixed up.

(1) NP as the class of NP complete problems:

For none of these problems, a polynomial algorithm has been found so far. It has been proven that if such an algorithm is found for one of these problems, each of them can be solved in polynomial time. The standard example for NP completeness is the Travelling Salesman problem.

(2) NP as a property of an algorithm that requires exponential time:

Any NP algorithm can be solved for small sizes N. The issue is just that the number of calculations increases exponentially (i.e. *very* quickly) with N.

There are problems for which originally only NP algorithms have been known but for which polynomial time algorithms have been found later. Unfortunately I cannot come up with an example right now.

For many problems that have only NP solutions, there exist polynomial time algorithms that produce good approximations of the optimal solutions. For many applications this is sufficient.

Comment: "NP is not a property of a problem but of the algorithm used to solve it." This seems misleading to me, if it refers to NP-completeness. Assuming P != NP, saying a decision problem is NP-hard means that no algorithm with polynomial running time can solve it. Either way, NP-hardness or -completeness are not properties of algorithms, but of problems. Time complexity is a property of an algorithm. And for what it's worth, if there is a definitive canonical example for NP completeness, it would almost certainly be SAT.

Comment: @G.Bach: You're right, I have modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's still wrong. Problems are in complexity classes, algorithms have (time and space) complexities. Also, NP and NPC are not the same thing. Checking if a given bit is 0 or 1 is a problem that's in NP, but certainly not in NPC.

Comment: @G.Bach: Assuming that the OP is not an expert on the topic, I tried to answer the question from a more practical point of view and made some simplifications.